# NGINX, uWSGI and Flask not running subprocess

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

My NGINX configuration:

```
server {
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  listen 4450;
  location ~* ^/.*$ {
  include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/esrvadmin.sock;
  }
}
```

uWSGI start up:

```
uwsgi --uid root -s /tmp/esrvadmin.sock --chown-socket nobody:root \
  --file /var/www/sitios/manten/srv.py \
  --processes 2 --callable app --pidfile /var/run/edesarrollos/esrvadmin.pid
```

Python with flask code:

```
import os, subprocess
from flask import Flask, abort, request
app = Flask(__name__)

DETO_DIR = '/var/www/sitios/manten/detos'

@app.route('/detonate')
def index():
  #return str(subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l']))
  token = request.args.get('token','')
  if token != '':
     # Si no existe el directorio de detonatores, se crea
     if not os.path.exists(DETO_DIR):
       os.mkdir(DETO_DIR)
     if os.path.isfile(DETO_DIR+"/"+token):
       try:
         os.system(open(DETO_DIR+"/"+token).read())
       except Exception as ex:
         return str(ex)
       return "Reiniciado Correctamente"
     else:
       abort(404) 
  else:
    abort(404)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

In **main** mode, i can run anything inside os.system("something args") and receive its HTTP response, even with "service something start" and it finish right. Also i tried with subprocess functions, no luck.

But when i run from NGINX-uWSGI, i get a waiting forever http request, of course never response but it does the job (starting a service).

The best error description in log i found:

```
2013/01/28 03:38:24 [error] 3978#0: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 
127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET
/detonate?token=start-    
a81260812b643d8672ccf9570033109f200595779e0a352e630a75760328e2d375025ef349e
3d599f368092abb63511f-23611e81194b04d5d0a6d0f02baf7fb9
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/esrvadmin.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:4450"
```

Any idea of what could be happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html (the --close-on-exec part) and please,please, please, DO NOT RUN uWSGI as root !

Comment: Thank you, "close-on-exec" worked great, just like i expected, BTW i know root risks, i'm just doing tests in my localhost.